# state is undefined in useLocation even after assigning the value in it

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

**state prop is undefined in useLocation hook in react , can access pathname but state is showing undefined**

```
{users.map((item) => {

                    return (<tr key={item.id}><td>{item.name} </td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td>{item.account}</td>
                        <td>{item.amount}</td>
                        <td><Link to={{pathname: `/users/${item.name}`, state: {
                                name: item.name,
                                account:item.account
                            }
                        }}> Transfer </Link></td>
                    </tr>)


                })}
```

**I'm passing, pathname, and state but can only access pathname , the state is undefined even after hardcoding the values on the directed component **

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams , useLocation} from 'react-router'
const Demo = ()=> {
const {transfer} = useParams()
const location = useLocation()
console.log(transfer ,location.state)
return (
    <div>
        hello {transfer}{location.state}
    </div>
)
}
```

**output : transfer , undefined

why location.state is undefined**

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it as below, [see docs e.g. here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link)

```
<td>
  <Link
    to = {`/users/${item.name}`}
    state = {{
      name: item.name,
      account: item.account,
    }}
  >
    {" "}
    Transfer{" "}
  </Link>
</td>;
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working... Issue is not with the pathname but with the state. As pathname is accessible but state is undefined

Comment: Are you accessing in the right component ? You can just log and check location.... I doubt you are logging in a different place

Comment: Yeah, the issue got resolved, I was using a different router version , so the issue was with syntax... Thanks for looking into the problem and helping